# How to get the 2d coordinates of webgl vertices?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl, coordinates

In this tutorial: http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=28 we draw a triangle and a square in the 3d space, and I want to get the vertices' x,y coordinates on the canvas.

So I want to get the 2d coordinates of these vertices: http://s11.postimage.org/ig6irk9lf/static.png

Sorry for my bad english, I hope you understand it.

Answer (score 6):

You have to do the same calculation that WebGL does.  It takes a 3d point `[X,Y,Z]` to homogeneous point `[x,y,z,w]` via

`[x,y,z,w] = pMatrix * mvMatrix * [X,Y,Z,1]`

To get clip space coordinates, divide through by `w`:

`[x/w,y/w,z/w]`

`x/w` and `y/w` are in the range [-1,1].  To convert them to viewport coordinates, scale them according to the canvas size.

`[x/w,y/w] -> [(1 + x/w)*canvas.width/2, (1 - y/w)*canvas.height/2]`

Note how the 'direction' of the y coordinate changes in the last transformation.

For a little more information, you can Google "graphics pipeline".  E.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_pipeline

Comment: @Danny, to understand `w` you need to understand homogeneous coordinates and how they are used in computer graphics. e.g. http://knol.google.com/k/perspective-transformation#Matrix_form_for_the_perspective_transform.  If you don't want to understand, just recognize that pMatrix is 4x4 and gives you an extra coordinate that you have to divide out to get back to three coordinates.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the math to compute them manually. WebGL only computes them for its own purposes, ie: rendering.

Desktop GL has ways of getting those positions back (transform feedback), but WebGL does not.

Comment: I have no idea, how to calculate it. :'(